# Data Studio Date Range Filter on hour, minute level

Tags: looker-studio

I am preparing a DataStudio report that reads data from BigQuery. It is a timeseries chart. I have applied date range filter. The date range filter gives filtering on date level. However, I need the range on hour/minute level. e.g. if i set date range filter from 18 march to 19 march, it will show me data on 18 march. However, I want to see data on 18 March between say 1700 to 1800. The date range filter is based on timestamp column in BigQuery table. How to do this, I don't see any documentation and/or option to set in date range filter.

Comment: dipeshk, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updated the post with a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e19f4c13-60d2-4646-8b9b-65bc152e602e) to demonstrate a **3 Step Process (each with a GIF to visualise)**:

### Step 1: Create a Date Hour Minute (YYYYMMDDhhmm) Field

Changing the *Type* of the *DateTime* field (at the Data Source) from the default `YYYYMMDD` to *Date Hour Minute* `YYYYMMDDhhmm` should do the trick (add the `YYYYMMDDhhmm` field as the primary dimension in the respective chart).

***Note***: As best practice, ensure that there is a YYYYMMDD date field (if there is just a single Date field, then duplicate it).

***GIF to elaborate on Step 1***:

[image: 2]]

### Step 2: Charts

There are a couple of chart types to consider:
**2.1) [Time Series Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697)**
- ***Dimension***: DateTime

**2.2) [Line Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7398001)**
- ***Dimension***: `TODATE(DateTime, "%H:%M")`
- ***Sort***: `TODATE(DateTime, "%H:%M")` in Ascending order

***GIF that details Step 2***:

[image: 5]]

### Step 3: Filter Controls

Create two [Filter Controls](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144), one for the *Start DateTime* that uses the comparison `>=` operator, and the second for *End DateTime* that utilises the `<=` comparison operator, both created using the following:
- ***Dimension***: `CAST(DateTime AS NUMBER )`
- ***Style***: Search All
- ***NOTE***: When using a Time Series Chart with the two Filter Controls, ensure that the [Date Range Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067) is set to *Auto Date Range*
- ***Use Case*** (to display values between 17:00 and 18:00 on the 18th of March 2020):
***Start Date*** `>=` `202003181700`
***End Date*** `<=` `202003181800`

***GIF that visualises Step 3***:

[image: 8]]