# Two Date Filters in Google Data Studio

Tags: sorting, datetime, google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a Google Sheet as the source data for a table in Google Data Studio. My table includes fields for "Sign Up Date" and "Cancellation Date".

I want to be able to filter so that I can choose a date range for "Sign Up Date" and a different date range for "Cancellation Date". For example, show me all records where the "Sign Up Date" is between Jan 1 to Jan 31, 2021, and where "Cancellation Date" is between Aug 1 to Aug 31, 2021.

As far as I can see you can only choose one Data Range Dimension per table, and any date filter you add is tied to that date field.

Is there any way I can have separate date filters for each of my date fields?

Answer (score 1):

Two [Range Slider](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/b44fe1f4-1d27-440f-a36a-392a3c361295/page/LoXKB) [Community Visualisations](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) could be used (one for each of the date fields, `Sign Up Date` and `Cancellation Date`).

## 1) Accessing the [Range Slider](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/b44fe1f4-1d27-440f-a36a-392a3c361295/page/LoXKB):

1. Click the [Community Visualisations and components](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) icon on the toolbar:
   [image: 3]
2. Select `+Explore more` to view all:
   [image: 4]
3. Choose the [Range Slider](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/b44fe1f4-1d27-440f-a36a-392a3c361295/page/LoXKB) chart from the displayed Community Gallery:
   [image: 5]
4. Click "Allow" to grant access to the respective [Community Visualisation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527):
   [image: 6]

## 2) Using the [Range Slider](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/b44fe1f4-1d27-440f-a36a-392a3c361295/page/LoXKB):

### 2.1) Sign Up Date Range Slider

Create both [Range Sliders](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/b44fe1f4-1d27-440f-a36a-392a3c361295/page/LoXKB) below and adjust the date range as required, in this case 01 Jan 2021 to 31 Jan 2021 for `Sign Up Date` and 01 Aug 2021 to 31 Aug 2021 for `Cancellation Date`:

- ***Column to filter on***: `Sign Up Date`
- ***Cross-filtering***: Select (☑) (this option makes sure the Range Slider also affects other charts)

### 2.2) Cancellation Date Range Slider

- ***Column to filter on***: `Cancellation Date`
- ***Cross-filtering***: Select (☑) (this option makes sure the Range Slider also affects other charts)

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1b8355dc-abad-42d1-877d-9f6312d26622) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IvtCclvXqJHBUKvKRGYVZywOpqIuHhwt-ey0rbhGraQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 9]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is not.
What you can do it make different versions of advanced filters and use the "Between" function to compare numeric values. So you have to convert dates to some kind of numeric value first. Here is an example for this:
[Data Studio Date Range Filter on hour, minute level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769183/data-studio-date-range-filter-on-hour-minute-level)